# De onde surgiu a gíria brasileira “pau” quando se refere a dinheiro?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

A palavra "pau" foi e ainda é usada como um dos sinônimos para dinheiro (no singular mesmo — linguagem coloquial e das ruas), porém de onde ela surgiu? Exs.:

- "*Isso aqui* custa *5 pau*"
- "Deu *100 pau* de desconto"

Comment: Tem uma pergunta semelhante no Ciberdúvidas da Língua Portuguesa, que se refere ao contexto de Portugal. O termo parece ser originado de lá. https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/paus-e-contos/9489

Answer (score 7):

Coisas como *cinco pau, cem pau* são uma variante popular brasileira de *cinco paus, cem paus*, que é uma gíria comum possivelmente a todos os países de língua portuguesa — não encontrei em São Tomé e Príncipe e Guiné-Bissau, mas possivelmente apenas porque há pouca coisa desses países na net.

E é uma gíria já antiga. No Brasil já estava em uso em 1895, como mostra este artigo no [*Jornal do Brasil* de 13 de janeiro de 1895](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030015_01&pesq=%22vinte%20paus%22&pasta=ano%20189&pagfis=3896) — um indivíduo empresta “20$” a um “inimigo íntimo” e fica muito contente, porque (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> — Pudera não? Aquelle sujeito mordeu-me **vinte páus.**
> — E é por isso que estás alegre assim?!
> — De certo! Poderia ter me mordido muito mais.

Em Portugal encontrei a partir de 1939, mas já num dicionário, no *Novo Dicionário da Língua Portuguesa* de Cândido de Figueiredo:

> **Pau** […] *Fam[iliar]* Dez tostões, um escudo: *gastou 20 paus no almôço*

Não encontrei nada sobre a razão de se chamar *pau* ao dinheiro, e imagino que não será fácil ou mesmo possível encontrar. Além das designações não-oficiais para unidades monetárias partilhadas por Portugal e Brasil, como *mil réis* que deu em *merréis*, *contos* e *paus*, existe, só em Portugal (possivelmente também no Brasil), uma quase infinidade de gírias para dinheiro, identificada por [Heinz Kröll em *O eufemismo e o disfemismo no português moderno* (Lisboa, 1984; p. 55-57)](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTwcnJpoLLAhUM7BQKHaMFCcYQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcvc.instituto-camoes.pt%2Fconhecer%2Fbiblioteca-digital-camoes%2Flingua-1%2F131-131%2Ffile.html&usg=AFQjCNHgnVFX1ARQJHFwB0RYVJ8LfPjfZA&bvm=bv.114733917,d.ZWU). Para dinheiro em geral há:

> *massa, massaroca, bagalhoça, c’roas, cobres, arame, bago baguinho, bagulho, caroço, cascalho, mosca, painço, cacau, carcanhóis, cebo, chinfres, ferros, guita, lecas, milho, naipe, pasta, pilim*

Falando-se de quantias pequenas, normalmente para se dizer que não se tem dinheiro:

> *chavo, chelpa, vintém*

Equivalente a *escudo*, a moeda portuguesa antes do euro, além de *paus*:

> *barrote, malho, mango, manguço, palhaço*

E depois ainda havia gírias para as notas: *bilhestres* e *pápulas* para notas em geral,  *lençóis* para notas de grande valor, *folha de alface* (20$), *linguado, pacote* ou *quilo* (1000$), *pintor* (100$) e *meio pintor* (50$).

Portanto parece que no que toca a gírias para dinheiro, o pessoal tem uma imaginação ilimitada.

---

### *Pau* versus *Paus*

O *pau* sem a marca de plural /s/ da língua padrão, é um fenómeno comum em certos falares populares brasileiros, em que (ver [Thaïs Cristófaro Silva, *Organização fonológica de marcas de plural no português brasileiro*](https://revistas.ufpr.br/abralin/article/view/32468)) :

> […] a marca do plural é preservada somente no constituinte mais à esquerda do sintagma nominal [nota de rodapé omitida] “o**s** menino**s** bonito**s**” e “o**s** menino bonito”, ou “un**s** dia**s** alegre**s**” e “un**s** dia alegre”.

É fácil de ver que o plural pode também ser marcado simplesmente pelo número: “**Quatro perna** tem a mesa, **quatro dia** o carnaval” ([Raul Seixas, *Os números*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WPz98A1aVjs)), “**dois pau** de jacarandá” ([Anais do Arquivo Público da Bahia, 1985](https://books.google.pt/books?id=AcULAAAAYAAJ&q=%22dois%20pau%20de%20jacarand%C3%A1%22&dq=%22dois%20pau%20de%20jacarand%C3%A1%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjDl9bZmYnsAhV75OAKHYh8DoIQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg)), “eu sustento **duas mulher**, e a minha mulher sustenta **dois home**” ([Gabriel O. Alvarez e Luiz Santos, *Tradições negras, políticas brancas*, 2006](https://books.google.pt/books?id=ztErAAAAYAAJ&q=%22sustento%20duas%20mulher%22&dq=%22sustento%20duas%20mulher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCno3YlonsAhXxAWMBHStLCn4Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg)).

*Paus* enquanto ’dinheiro’ é gíria, e é possível que na gíria o pessoal tenha mais tendência a usar formas de expressão popular, e daí a não marcação do plural no *pau* de *cinco pau, cem pau*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Vim procurar se alguém tinha uma explicação para os *paus*, porque acho que tenho a explicação!

Estou a ler um livro acerca da evolução da ideia de dívida e da origem do dinheiro chamado ["Debt, the first 5000 years" do autor David Graeber (testo integral)](https://libcom.org/files/__Debt__The_First_5_000_Years.pdf). Lá ele conta que em Inglaterra era muito comum os comerciantes emitirem notas de dívida utilizando ramos de árvores! Imaginem que eu sou um talhante e quero comprar uns sapatos, chego ao sapateiro e adoraria pagar em salsichas MAS ele já tem carne para o mês... Ora aí lembro-me que nessa semana vendi bifes ao ferreiro da vila e que ele me emitiu uma promessa de pagamento de dívida na forma de um ramo quebrado.
Esta nota de dívida era de tal forma aceite entre comerciantes que eu poderia então pagar a minha conta no sapateiro com a "moeda" emitida pelo ferreiro.

Reparem que isto sou eu a fazer uma ligação e não encontrei nada que mostrasse que este era o hábito em Portugal e portanto nada indica directamente que levamos estes "paus" para os mercados africanos e/ou brasileiros mas é uma coincidência engraçada e uma possível resposta.

Como última curiosidade, o pau que o comerciante emitia e era entregue ao cliente era chamado de "stub" que ainda hoje é o nome que os ingleses dão ao restinho de papel que nós entregamos quando o nosso bilhete de entrada num teatro, cinema ou jogo de futebol é picado à entrada.

Comment: Nuno, bem-vindo ao site. Isto foi uma grande descoberta. Esse sistema existiu em Portugal. Chamava-se *talha* (*tally* em inglês, ambos do latim *talea*). Era usado como registo: no pau talhavam-se marcas que indicavam a quantia em dívida. O Houaiss diz que também servia como prova de pagamento. O Bluteau em 1728, diz que ferreiros e "outros officiaes" usavam isso para registar dívidas de clientes. O Morais Silva em 1789 diz que os "rústicos" usavam isso para registar quantidades de lenha e outras coisas; uma *talha* era também uma certo número de molhos de lenha, carradas de alguma coisa; >>

Comment: >> imagino, que faziam uma marca no pau por cada "talha". Também houve um imposto chamado talha (Idade Média, ainda vem nas Ordenações Filipinas, por volta de 1600). O teu livro diz que esses "tally sticks" serviam para registar quantias desse imposto. Não sei se essas talhas alguma vez circularam como dinheiro. O teu livro diz, que eram os "tally sticks" do Henrique II, 1154-1189, que circularam como dinheiro. Agora, é uma granda salto, dizer que foi isto que originou o uso de *pau* = ’escudo,  etc.’ Pode ter sido, ou pode ter sido uma invenção qualquer; >>

Comment: >> então depois também teria de haver uma explicação deste tipo para todos os outros termos que o pessoal usou para dinheiro -- caroço, bago, carcanhol, etc.?

Comment: Encontrei o livro em PDF na net, e linkei-o na tua resposta.